# Magento add custom attribute to transaction email items

Tags: magento-1, email, transactional-mail, items

I want to change the default SKU field inside the transactional email item field, to a custom attribute.

Therefore I need to edit the following file:

```
/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

I want to change the following value:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?>
```

My custom attribute value is "dpn" and it is named "DPN".

How can I change this?

I tried the following but that does not work:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDpn($_item)) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that calling `$this->getSku()` or `$this->getDpn()` is referring to a method that you can/could find in the related *Block*, in your case:

`app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Default.php`

in which you'll find the relevant `getSku()` method. You could in turn extend this class and add your `getDpn()` method, but I believe what you are trying to do it get a product's attribute.

If it's the case, you only have to do

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getDpn()) ?>
```

But be aware that it might be costly because Magento will internally call `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Item.php:getProduct()` which instantiates the given product.